# Will the Reader Gets Closed

Tags: ado.net

```
 public string GetSomething()
        { var a = String.Empty; 

            try 
            {
               // loop through the datareader 

                return "some data"; 
            }

            finally
            {
                reader.close(); 
            }

            return whatever; 
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the finally block will get executed.  You may want to call reader.dispose().  I like to use the using{} statement myself.

Answer (score 0):

Code in a finally block *always* runs.  [See here](http://www.discussweb.com/c-programming/2448-if-i-return-out-try-finally-c-does-code-finally-clause-run.html).